# Visual Studio компиляция C++ проекта под Linux

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, компиляция

Есть C++ проект в Visual Studio 2017, нужно скомпилировать его для дальнейшего запуска на Linux(Ubuntu) какие существуют варианты для реализации?

Comment: Visual Studio с недавних пор [поддерживает разработку под Linux из коробки](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/04/11/linux-development-with-c-in-visual-studio/).

Answer (score 1):

Я бы предложил попробовать перенести проект из Visual Studio в Qt Creator с использованием компилятора VC++. Затем когда проект получится собирать из Qt creator - установить MinGW и пробовать собрать с ним, исправляя все ошибки и предупреждения.
Затем уже на Linux можно ставить Qt Creator и там пробовать собирать gcc.

По своему опыту могу сказать, что VС++ дает больше вольностей по сравнению с gcc. Приходилось много правок вносить в код с шаблонами. Так же оказало что `std::exception` на самом деле нельзя конструировать, а нужно использовать производные классы `std::runtime_error` или пр. Так же стоит помнить, в linux файловая система регистрозависимая. Если файл на диске назван как `Header.h`, то и подключать его надо так же `#include <Header.h>`, в то время как в Windows работают варианты `#include <header.h>`, `#include <hEaDeR.h>`

Comment: Для сборки посредством mingw / gcc qt creator не нужен ни на windows, ни на Linux.

Comment: @VTT, согласен, можно и в блокноте код писать, но зачем?

Comment: Да, только компилятор не vc, а gcc. Так будет кроссплатформенно. Вдобавок под windows я бы советовал компилятор не тот, который идет в комплекте с qt, а MinGW-w64. Его можно даже не устанавливать в windows, а просто распаковать в отдельный каталог и разрулить пути.